# aumentar velocidade de resposta do cURL?

Tags: php

Estou usando uma API do google e estou testando ela com o código abaixo, porém há uma diferença enorme no carregamento direto pelo browser e pelo PHP, ela demora muito pelo PHP, existe alguma maneira de "acelerar" isso?

```
    $this -> curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($this -> curl, CURLOPT_URL, ltrim($this -> queryURL() . '&q=' . urlencode($this -> query)));
    curl_setopt($this -> curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($this -> curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $this -> response = curl_exec($this -> curl);

    curl_close($this -> curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mais algumas opções de *timeout* antes do `curl_exec`:

```
curl_setopt($this -> curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1); // espera 1 segundo para conectar

curl_setopt($this -> curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); // espera ateh 10 segundos no envio de comandos
```

Baseado em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php

Ah, e existe a opção para passar os parâmetros em ms:
`CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` e `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS`

Comment: Ambas servem pra otimização?